# rake task does not launch for lack of Mime JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rake

After installing a repository locally and bundling for a rails 4.0 application, the database creation

```
rake db:create
```

command fails returning the following error:

```
uninitialized constant Mime::JSON
```

invoking from application.rb this particular line

```
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)
```

this line is preceeded by:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'
```

How can I get rake to properly process?

** update **
as per request full stack trace follows.  I did manage to avoid the error by removing the jbuilder gem.

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Mime::JSON
/Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/jbuilder-1.5.3/lib/jbuilder/jbuilder_template.rb:110:in `<class:JbuilderHandler>'
/Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/jbuilder-1.5.3/lib/jbuilder/jbuilder_template.rb:108:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/jbuilder-1.5.3/lib/jbuilder.rb:358:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `require'
/Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:69:in `each'
/Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:69:in `block in require'
/Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:58:in `each'
/Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:58:in `require'
/Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler.rb:174:in `require'
/Volumes/Mo/r/uelcom/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Volumes/Mo/r/uelcom/Rakefile:8:in `require'
/Volumes/Mo/r/uelcom/Rakefile:8:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load'
/Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:703:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'
/Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in run'
/Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/bin/rake:23:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `load'
/Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `kernel_load'
/Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
/Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/cli.rb:476:in `exec'
/Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
/Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:399:in `dispatch'
/Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/cli.rb:30:in `dispatch'
/Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:476:in `start'
/Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/cli.rb:24:in `start'
/Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/exe/bundle:46:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:123:in `with_friendly_errors'
/Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/exe/bundle:34:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Can you please add the full backtrace of the exception?

Comment: the question was updated.

Comment: Can you please share your Gemfile

Comment: Are you using rails 5 and above ?

Comment: no 4.0... a bit of a mess, as many gems and isues popped up.

Comment: OK, Asked since this might confuse future reader while reading the accepted answer. Does the answer solves your question?

Comment: I believe so, but I just cannot be certain as too many balls were being juggled. In one iteration that element seemed to pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using rails 5 or above.

As of rails version 5 or above accessing Mime types through `Mime::JSON` is deprecated, We need to access it as `Mime[:json]`

Please find the following references for the same - [Release Note](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/5_0_release_notes.html#action-pack-deprecations) and [Pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/21869)

> Deprecated accessing mime types via constants (eg. Mime::HTML). Use the subscript operator with a symbol instead (eg. Mime[:html])

---

As per the backtrace of the exception you have given, the gem `jbuilder` is causing the issue, which accesses Mime types as `Mime::JSON` which is deprecated.

Please find the reference of the line which causes the error on the gem jbuilder - [Jubilder - Github](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder/blob/v1.5.3/lib/jbuilder/jbuilder_template.rb#L110).

You are using the older version of the `jbuilder(1.5.3)`, please upgrade this gem to the latest version and try

Try the below version:

***Gemfile***

```
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.10'
```